# How to generate network-traversal key?

Tags: javascript, google-api, network-programming

```
 var f = new XMLHttpRequest;
f.onreadystatechange = 
c, f.open("POST","https://networktraversal.googleapis.com/v1alpha/iceconfig?key=AIzaSyDsOZCTqASEd-gpahM7OIGMAHGDj_PS7nI", !0), f.send()
```

Could you please suggest that how can we get this key as like below-
**AIzaSyDsOZCTqASEd-gpahM7OIGMAHGDj_PS7nI** ?

Answer (score 1):

The key in question is a public api key.  Public api keys are used to access public data on Googles apis.

A public API key is created on [Google developer console.](https://console.developers.google.com)